# Link to a product list not working in Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

I am an Android Developer and I publish apps to Google Play. I provide my users a link to all my published apps under the option "More by us"

I used the format provided [here](http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/linking.html#OpeningPublisher). This process was working fine, but today I found that not all my apps are showing up. Beside this, many apps from other publishers are also suggested. But that is not the point of "More by us" option at all.

Note: I have tried the way described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26203450/1007378). This shows all my apps in desktop browser, but I face same problem when opened in Google Play app on Android devices.

What should I do? Is Google shutting down the facility or it is just a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We face the same issue...

Have you tried contacting Google, we just found out today and the issue could've been there for 2 months (we have been using the pub link in all apps for years without issue). In our case our vendor name has a " " (space) in it, but we tried other vendors with spaces and they all worked ok.

The workaround so far is to use "http://play.google.com/store/search?q=pub:Name+of+vendor" Use + sign for space.

This works, but this is triggering the open with window and it also requires us to update every single app.